# Updating AngularJS View when user action has completed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing some small exercises to teach myself AngularJS and I'm trying to write some simple user Authorisation tasks. I have a form to collect/input a username and password, these are then sent to a rest service using `$http` and CORS (as my REST service is running on a different port), they are checked and if there is a match I return a UUID and create a token and I `$broadcast` a loggedIn value to true that is on the `$rootScope`, something like this.

```
// this is in a service I call 'authService'

this.login = function (user) {

    return $http({method: 'POST', url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/login', data: user})
        .then(function (response) {

            // set up a local storage token
            storageService.setLocalStorage('token', response.data[0].uuid);
            // broadCast is loggedIn - we have a match
            $rootScope.loggedInUser = true; // this is set to false at the .run() of the app
            $rootScope.$broadcast('LoggedIn');

            return 1;
        }, function () {
            // return http code later
            return 0;
        });

    };

    this.getLoggedIn = function () {
        return  $rootScope.loggedInUser;
    };
```

Now in a separate menu view I have the following condition (the authService is added as a dependancy on the menu controller):

```
<div id="logIn" ng-show="!authService.getLoggedIn()">...</div>
```

Now when I load the app for the first time the condition is correct, however I want this condition to update should a user log in correctly (so the div) isn't shown. In the menu controller I have the following code, none of it seems to do anything?

```
   $scope.$on('LoggedIn', function () {
        authService.getLoggedIn(); // doesn't update the view?
        console.log($rootScope.loggedInUser); // returns true
        console.log(authService.getLoggedIn()); // returns true
    });

$scope.$watch('loggedInUser', function () {
    console.log('loggedInUser has changed ' + $rootScope.loggedInUser);
    // This runs once when we set $rootScope.loggedInUser in the .run() of the app, output is: 'loggedInUser has changed false' 
    // then when we have successfully logged in again, output is 'loggedInUser has changed true'
});
```

Okay, so the condition on the `<div>` in my menu view doesn't update when I changed the $rootScope.loggedInUser, I'm doing something wrong in my approach, can someone give me some advice or correct my approach to this. Thanks

Comment: `ng-show` bind to a scope value like `$scope.isLogon` or a scope function that return true or false. `authService.getLoggedIn()` is not defined or at least not in the code you show here. So means `authService.getLoggedIn()` always false.

Comment: Sorry, authService.getLoggedIn() is defined in a service that I add as a dependancy into the menu controller so when I log in the console.log(authService.getLoggedIn()); and $scope.$watch('loggedInUser' function(){}) are fired in the controller but the view isn't updated?

Comment: the view don have access to authService, can you do  proxy `authService.getLoggedIn()` in your menu controller. like `$scope. getAuth = function() { return authService.getLoggedIn() }`. also I don't really see the need to involve rootScope in your usecase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special in Angular to update view when some prop is updated, provided it is in the correct scope. I provided a Plunkr for you which demonstrates that you don't have to do anything special to refresh the view.

http://plnkr.co/edit/B6kUwJdA4lRKkjAItSFO?p=preview

You don't have to do watches, you don't have to do anything. That is the power of Angular. Also, it is weird that you set stuff in rootscope. My advice for you is to look at my example and revise/restructure your code. Also, having stuff like this:

`ng-show="!authService.getLoggedIn()"`

Is not the recommended way of doing things. You can have a controller, in which you say:

```
$scope.userLoggedIn = autService.getLoggedIn();
```

and then in your view:

```
ng-show="userLoggedIn"
```

You can also take a look at this plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/aRhS0h7BgpJJeRNvnosQ?p=preview